# What does scaffolding mean in Helm Chart and what are the use cases for creating scaffolding?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is it correct to say that a scaffolding in Helm Chart is a Chart based on another Chart with your own customization?

If that's correct why don't we just customize values.yaml instead? If we need to change the configuration why don't we write a new Chart instead?

what are the use cases for creating a scaffolding?

Answer (score 1):

`helm create xyz` just builds you a starting structure in whuch you can develop the chart needed for your `xyz` project.  It has no relationship to any existing chart.

The use-case is 'programmer who prefers not to start with a blank sheet of paper'.